# Update source code of iOs app

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-3

The review process with Apple takes a lot of time. It's ok to wait a week for the first published version and for major upgrades - but to wait for review for minor changes (that might not even be visible to most users) can be a bit annoying.

Since most changes happen in the www-files, it should be possible to update these files dynamically so that the app updates the www-source itself. (And thus make changes to the app without Apple review it again).

Any tips on how to do this, or any plugins that handle this update?

PS: I am aware that Apple guidelines prohibit downloading "executable code", but I think only using this for minor updates of the www-source is within what's acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

The files within your app's bundle (where your `www` directory lives) are immutable. Even if you download new files to the device, they cannot replace your existing `www` files. You would need to place the new files in a mutable location (`Documents` or somewhere in `Library` and then execute the code from that particular location.

As long as you download *content*, you'll be fine. Content should be able to include limited code (enough to link up event handling, etc.), but don't go overboard on this, as Apple may not see it the same way you do.

As for downloading code that *modifies the app's behavior* without passing through Apple's review process, **don't**. That *will* get your app rejected, even if technically possible.

In other words, if in doubt, pass it through Apple review.

Comment: Great. Does PhoneGap 3.2 allow to dynamically change the location of the index.html file to be executed?

Answer (score 0):

You could consider this plugin: https://github.com/markmarijnissen/cordova-app-loader